# Are electrode based, water level monitoring systems safe?

Tags: sensor, controller, water, electrode

I want to install a pump control with water level monitoring system.

I've seen all kind of sensors, ultrasonic, infrared, mechanical (Based in pressure switch's / float valves), etc.

One of the most interesting systems, its based on electrodes submerged in water, apparently the system consist of 3 or more electrodes. There is a "Common anode / catode" in the bottom, and other electrodes placed at different heights to detect the water levels. I suppose the controller detects an small electric current between the common electrode and the its counterparts.

[image: Example of this system]

What i like, is that there is a lot of commercial systems, so no need to start from scratch. They can detect levels on multiple tanks and activate / deactivate the pump depending of the water levels. But what I'm worried about:

1. Generally systems require you to submerse electric cables to your tank. If we are talking about drinkable water, it could present a risk of chemical leaching overtime. Most electric cables have PVC with fire retardant's. Probably negligible, but if i can get away with my water being free of phthalates and bromine / halogen compounds it would be much better.
2. Systems use copper,  stainless or bronze  electrodes. They work at 12V, Maybe there is a possibility of an small electrolysis / galvanic corrosion over time?. That could affect the water quality placing trace amounts of this metals on the water?, that would eat the electrodes overtime?.

I could manufacture or purchase an electrode system without exposed electric cables, and using mostly innocuous plastics as rigid PVC for water or polyethylene with small exposed electrodes made of copper or stainless steel, solving the first issue. But not sure if can solve the second one.

[image: Example of a system without exposed electric cable]

So, are this type of systems reliable and safe?, or should i start looking for other solution?

Comment: Concerning the electrical part: How safe such a system is depends on **how you use it** and **how it is designed**. For electrolysis to happen there needs to be some (DC) voltage between the electrodes, if a low voltage at low current is used there will be less electrolysis. Use AC and there is none. *They work at 12V* Is there 12 V across the electrodes? I would doubt that. The electronics may need 12 V, that doesn't mean there's 12 V across the sensor.

Comment: Good insights, i just found some information about the voltage across electrodes, seems to be 2V ac with 7uA with this particular manufacturer, and they claim their stainless electrodes would never rust with those parameters: file:///tmp/mozilla_david0/Checkpoint-Information-Sheet-1.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You should be looking for systems labeled specifically for food and beverage/potable water applications.  That way you know that they've been designed to not leach any potentially hazardous chemicals into the water and have been tested to confirm that. There are also reflective ultrasonic level sensors which are completely non-contact.

Answer (score 1):

For pump operation , low duty cycle operation is better with 3 probes: start, gnd, stop with high quality SS probes with an interface suitable for your controller connections.